Is there GitHub API to obtain the selected text from a diff hunk on which the particular Pull Request comment is "hung"?
So I know how to fetch the Pull Request comments and reviews and review comments using GitHub API - it is all documented.
What is NOT documented is how can I obtain the selection associated with the comment, e.g.:

I know how to fetch the comment text and the entire diff hunk (using the PR comments API), but I have no idea how to get the selection in the diff hunk associated with the comment.
For example, for the picture above I get the following payload from the Github Rest Api:

The only remotely relevant information in this context is this:
    "start_line": null,
    "original_start_line": null,
    "start_side": null,
    "line": 41,
    "original_line": 41,
    "side": "LEFT",
    "original_position": 40,
    "position": 40,
    "subject_type": "line"

But what does it mean? The selection affects lines 38-41, but the returned JSON does not communicate it.
So - how can we get it?
EDIT 1
I would like to provide more context on the example in this post. The review comment in the conversation tab clearly shows 4 lines, but the JSON response only mentions line #41 - the last one.
Here is the diff view of the same comment:

What I understand from the folks who replied is that the comment actually talks about the line 41, but the view in the Conversation tab simply selects more lines to show. In this case GitHub decided to show 4 lines.
But I have other review comments in the Conversation tab where it shows 5 lines (3 lines of context and 2 lines of change, which is the entire diff hunk):

The respective Diff view:

And the JSON response:

The entire diff hunk:
C:\> jq -r '.[]|select(.id == 1813888775).diff_hunk' C:\temp\3.json
@@ -25,15 +19,11 @@
   "BackgroundJobTests.AzureBlob.TestAzureBlob": "Payroll",
   "BackgroundJobTests.BackgroundJobHelperTest": "WFM",
   "BackgroundJobTests.BaseRateUpdate.EmployeeStatusTestData": "WFM",
-  "BackgroundJobTests.BaseRateUpdate.JobSetLevelRateRepositoryTest": "WFM",
-  "BackgroundJobTests.BaseRateUpdate.JobSetLevelRateRepositoryTestBuilder": "WFM",
C:\>

So I am a bit confused here. How does GitHub decide what to show in the Conversation tab view?

That comment looks to me like it's only anchored on line 41, not on the four-line block shown, so the answer is simply "line": 41 is what you're looking for. If you leave a comment on a single line, the GUI shows it and the previous 3. If you leave a comment anchored on multiple lines, those lines are shown and the text Comment on lines +14 to +16 is displayed above the lines shown.

I just read your edits to the question, and now you're asking something beyond my ken. How GitHub determines the snippet to display, who knows? But taking a sample of PR comments in my repos, I see 4 lines of it's all +, and 2 or 3 per side if it's a mix.

It is very confusing indeed. At the beginning I thought the selection is just not returned correctly, but your answer (which I +1ed) implies the reviewer actually selected 1 line. So I am back to my original need - how can we know what portion of the diff hunk is actually presented in the respective conversation pane?

Ah, so your requirement is not just to find out what the reviewer clicked on, but rather to find out what should get displayed. Tricky. My approach would be to make lots of experimental observations: look at a bunch of examples, and create a bunch more examples. Because you're trying to get at undocumented details of code that is not open-source, I don't think you'll get any better an answer than this (rather annoying) suggestion.

TL;DR
The line field is what you're looking for, and the start_line field when a comment is anchored on more than one line.
My observations
The comment you are showing is formatted like a comment anchored on just one line in the diff.
For validation, I just added a random comment on one line of a PR and it looks like this:

Here I had left a comment on line 10.
If leave a comment anchored on three lines, you get Comment on lines +14 to +16 displayed above the context:

Your screen capture
So in the example you show, your screen capture indicates that the comment is anchored on line 41 alone, which is what "line": 41 and "start_line": null is telling you.
Start line for multi-line comments
If the comment was anchored on multiple lines, start_line would show the "first line of the range for a multi-line comment" according to the documentation (Credits go to @nik0x1 for this link, which I borrowed from their now deleted answer.)
